# Capture the screen selected by Current Form in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, screen-capture

I am creating a application which can capture the screen which is selected by current active windows form and make user aware by setting it as the background of it. Please refer the image

[image]

But my problem is i cant get the size of the active window size. This is the code i have been working on

```
 private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        Image b = null;
        int w = (int)this.Width;
        int h = (int)this.Height;
        **System.Drawing.Size sz = this.Size;
        System.Drawing.Point loc = this.Location;**
        Hide();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        using (b = new Bitmap(w, h))
        {
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
            {
                g.CopyFromScreen(loc, new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0), sz);
            }

            Image x = new Bitmap(b);

            ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
            x.Save(@"C:\Users\DZN\Desktop\testBMP.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            myBrush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"C:\Users\DZN\Desktop\testBMP.jpeg", UriKind.Absolute));
            this.Background = myBrush;

        }
        Show();
    }
```

In the bolded lines i get the error saying WpfApplication1.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for 'Size, location. but this works well in windows forms. Any help is hugly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you added `System.Drawing` reference ?

Comment: Why is your screenshot and text a “form” when you’re using WPF instead of WinForms?

Comment: I have already mentioned it sir. I could do it in win forms. but in WPF i have a problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WPF Window doesn't have a size property instead you can use `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`. Same way it doesn't exposes  `Location` also but you can use `Left` and `Top` properties.

All the above properties are of type `double` so you need a cast to appropriate type.

```
System.Drawing.Size sz = new System.Drawing.Size((int)ActualWidth, (int)ActualHeight);
System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point((int)Left, (int)Top);
```

Comment: sir how can i convert it? i tried to do it. but still get the same error

Comment: System.Drawing.Size sz = ( )this.ActualWidth; sorry i know this is not a good questioin sir. but sir will you tell me appropriate type here? Thank you

Comment: I am confused with it sir. i get what you say. but i tried everythig to correct those two lines with the instructions. still i am unable to correct it sir.

Comment: Thank you sir. i tried it. but still it says about convertion error here sir.   System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Size((int)Left, (int)Top);

Comment: sir it should be System.Drawing.Point loc = new System.Drawing.Point((int)Left, (int)Top);

Comment: Oops that was a typo.. and thanks for your edit @poke